# SPFX web part to add Text and show it inside a Popup when clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I am trying to achieve this using SPFX web part:-

- The web part will render a Button and has a text field inside its settings.
- The user add the Web Part >> edit it >> enter the text inside the text field (inside the setting page) >> save the web part>> then the web part will render a button >> if the user clicks on the button a popup will be shown with the entered text.

Now I found this link @ https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/conecpt-of-react-portal-in-spfx/ which almost achieves what I am looking for, except that the Popup text inside the example is been hard-coded inside the `.tsx` file.. so what are the steps to make the Popup text configurable inside the web part settings instead of been hard-coded?

Thanks

Here is my `ReactPortalWebPart.ts` file:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';

import * as strings from 'ReactPortalWebPartStrings';
import ReactPortal from './components/ReactPortal';
import { IReactPortalProps } from './components/IReactPortalProps';

export interface IReactPortalWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export default class ReactPortalWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IReactPortalWebPartProps> {

  public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> = React.createElement(
      ReactPortal,
      {
        description: this.properties.description
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }

  protected onDispose(): void {
    ReactDom.unmountComponentAtNode(this.domElement);
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

and here is the `ReactPortal.tsx`:-

```
import * as React from 'react';  
    import { IReactPortalProps } from './IReactPortalProps';  
    import Myportal from "./Myportal";  
    export default class ReactPortal extends React.Component<IReactPortalProps, {}> {  
      public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> {  
        return (  
          <div >  
          <Myportal/>  
          </div>  
        );  
      }  
    }
```

Here is the `Myportal.tsx`:-

```
    import* as React from "react";  
    import usePortal from "react-cool-portal";  
    import "./mystyle.scss";  
    const  Myportal = () => {  
     // const { Portal } = usePortal({ containerId: "my-portal-root" });  
      const { Portal, show, hide } = usePortal({ defaultShow: false,containerId:"my-portal-root" });  
      const handleClickBackdrop = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {  
        const { id } = e.target as HTMLDivElement;  
        if (id === "modal") hide();  
      };  
      
      return (  
            <div className="App">  
         
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Who we are 
          </button>  
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Our value 
          </button> 
          <Portal>  
            <div  
              id="modal"  
              className="modal"  
              onClick={handleClickBackdrop}  
              tabIndex={-1}  
            >  
              <div  
                className="modal-dialog"  
                role="dialog"  
                aria-labelledby="modal-label"  
                aria-modal="true"  
              >  
                <div className="modal-header">  
                
                  <button  
                    className="modal-close"  
                    onClick={hide}  
                    type="button"  
                    aria-label="Close"  
                  >  
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>  
                  </button>  
                </div>  
                <div className="modal-body">  
                 <h1> Who we are</h1>
<h3>.................................................</h3>
Our overriding purpose is to dramatically improve the reliability, efficiency........
                </div>  
              </div>  
            </div>  
          </Portal>  
        </div>  
          
      );  
    };  
    export default Myportal;
```

Comment: It is not clear what you mean here. If you want the dialog to access the text stored in the web part properties, why don't you just pass it over to your dialog from your webpart??

Comment: @Nikolay yes i want inside the web part setting to add the needed HTML... then when the web part render the button and the user clicks on the button to display the HTML... i know my requirement sound simple.. but i am not sure how i can do it? thanks

Comment: @Nikolay can you please check my edit.. i provided the code for my SPFX.. thanks

Comment: Hmm why are you using portals?! Can't you simply render your web part, without any portals? I mean, pass the "description" to the component where you want to render it (here it's called "MyPortal" and does not have any properties. You need to pass the description to this component). Maybe this could help: what are components and properties in React: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: @Nikolay i am following this link @ https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/conecpt-of-react-portal-in-spfx/ for showing the popup.. thanks.. can you advice more on this?

Comment: Ah, you are using "react-cool-portal" library for the dialog, that's where the term "portals" is coming from. My bad, I thought you are using react portals (https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), sorry for the confusion. Still you need to pass your description property to the "Myportal" from "ReactPortal" as a property. I guess the last answer here illustrates it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to re-write `MyPortal` as a React Component; bellow I'm tried written some example about this change that needed on `MyPortal.tsx` and `ReactPortal.tsx`, but I do not test then.

`ReactPortal.tsx`:

```
import * as React from 'react';  
    import { IReactPortalProps } from './IReactPortalProps';
    import { IMyportalProps } from './IMyportalProps'; 
    import Myportal from "./Myportal";  
    export default class ReactPortal extends React.Component<IReactPortalProps, {}> {  
      public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps, IMyportalProps> {  
        return (  
          <div >  
          <Myportal title="Who we are" body="Our overriding purpose is to dramatically improve the reliability, efficiency........"/>  
          </div>  
        );  
      }  
    }
```

`MyPortal.tsx`

```
    import* as React from "react";  
    import usePortal from "react-cool-portal";  
    import "./mystyle.scss";
    export interface IMyportalProps {
       title: string;
       body: string
    }
    class Myportal extends React.Component  
<IMyportalProps> {    
       constructor(props: IUnderstandStateComponentProps) {    
       super(props);
    }
    public render(): React.ReactElement  
    <IMyportalProps> {  
      const { Portal, show, hide } = usePortal({ defaultShow: false,containerId:"my-portal-root" });  
      const handleClickBackdrop = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {  
        const { id } = e.target as HTMLDivElement;  
        if (id === "modal") hide();  
      };  
      
      return (  
            <div className="App">  
         
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Who we are 
          </button>  
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Our value 
          </button> 
          <Portal>  
            <div  
              id="modal"  
              className="modal"  
              onClick={handleClickBackdrop}  
              tabIndex={-1}  
            >  
              <div  
                className="modal-dialog"  
                role="dialog"  
                aria-labelledby="modal-label"  
                aria-modal="true"  
              >  
                <div className="modal-header">  
                
                  <button  
                    className="modal-close"  
                    onClick={hide}  
                    type="button"  
                    aria-label="Close"  
                  >  
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>  
                  </button>  
                </div>  
                <div className="modal-body">  
                 <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
<h3>.................................................</h3>
{this.props.body}
                </div>  
              </div>  
            </div>  
          </Portal>  
        </div>  
          
      );  
    };
```

Comment: I think rewriting it as a "react component" is not really required, you can just claim that thing is already a react "functional component". All you need to do is to pass properties to it (as arguments). But you can rewrite it as a class as well, yes.

Answer (score 2):

My attempt :)
The idea is, you pass the "description" from the web part down to the dialog.
Please read [the link above](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), how to pass properties in React from parent to the child components (or some basic React tutorial), it is highly recommended if you have chosen to work with SPFx using React.

Please note that an easier approach to create dialogs in SPFx coulod be, to use the Microsoft [Fluent UI](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui) library, it works great with SPFx, has many tutorials, supports SharePoint themes, etc. In particular, it has the "[Dialog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/dialog)" component built-in, among dozens of other useful components and controls.

Anyway, here we go with 'react-cool-portal'. Check out the comments in the code below.

ReactPortal.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';  
    import { IReactPortalProps } from './IReactPortalProps';  
    import Myportal from "./Myportal";  
    export default class ReactPortal extends React.Component<IReactPortalProps, {}> {

      // pass further the parameter that was received from the web part.
      // The "description was passed to "ReactPortal" from WebPart with:
      // React.createElement(
      //   ReactPortal,
      //   {
      //     description: this.properties.description
      //   }

      public render(): React.ReactElement<IReactPortalProps> {  
        return (  
          <div>  
          <!-- pass the parameter down to the child component -->
          <Myportal description={this.props.description} />  
          </div>  
        );  
      }  
    }
```

Myportal.tsx

```
    import* as React from "react";  
    import usePortal from "react-cool-portal";  
    import "./mystyle.scss";  

    // accept properties (added "props" argument)
    // and use it below in HTML {props.description}

    const  Myportal = (props) => {  
     // const { Portal } = usePortal({ containerId: "my-portal-root" });  
      const { Portal, show, hide } = usePortal({ defaultShow: false,containerId:"my-portal-root" });  
      const handleClickBackdrop = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {  
        const { id } = e.target as HTMLDivElement;  
        if (id === "modal") hide();  
      };  
      
      return (  
            <div className="App">  
         
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Who we are 
          </button>  
         &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button className="btn" onClick={show} type="button">  
            Our value 
          </button> 
          <Portal>  
            <div  
              id="modal"  
              className="modal"  
              onClick={handleClickBackdrop}  
              tabIndex={-1}  
            >  
              <div  
                className="modal-dialog"  
                role="dialog"  
                aria-labelledby="modal-label"  
                aria-modal="true"  
              >  
                <div className="modal-header">  
                
                  <button  
                    className="modal-close"  
                    onClick={hide}  
                    type="button"  
                    aria-label="Close"  
                  >  
                    <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>  
                  </button>  
                </div>  
                <div className="modal-body">  
                 <h1> Who we are</h1>
<!-- use the property value somehow -->
<h3>{props.description}</h3>
                </div>  
              </div>  
            </div>  
          </Portal>  
        </div>  
          
      );  
    };  
    export default Myportal;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways.

1. Storing the popup content as part of the page property that is persisted once you edit the page
2. Storing the popup content in a list and fetching the data whenever the page is render. FYI, haven't fully thought about how to achieve it via this way.

I have updated relevant sections of the code you provided to show how to achieve the expected by storing the popup content as part of the page property.

Added another property to the props to store the popup content

```
export interface IReactPortalWebPartProps {
description: string;
content?: string;
}
```

Updated the render method of the component `ReactPortalWebPart.ts`

```
    public render(): void {
      const element: React.ReactElement<any> = React.createElement(
        ReactPortal,
        {
          mode: this.displayMode, //used to determine if to display the text input or not based on the current state of the webpart.
          content: this.properties.content, //the contents property of the webpart which is persisted in the page properties.
          description: this.properties.description,
          updateWebPartContent: this.updateWebPartContentProperty.bind(this) // the function that would be called from the portal component when the content is saved by the user
        }
      );

    private updateWebPartContentProperty(htmlcontent) {
      //console.log( htmlcontent )
      //console.log( this.properties.content )
      this.properties.content = htmlcontent;
      this.onPropertyPaneFieldChanged( 'content', this.properties.content, htmlcontent );
      //console.log( this.properties.content )
    }
```

Passing the properties from `ReactPortal` to the `Myportal` functional component.

```
      <Myportal
        _mode={ this.props.mode }
        _content={ this.props.content }
        _updateWebPartContent={ this.props.updateWebPartContent } 
      />
```

Updated the functional component with the props object, added the hook to save the input from the user and also using the current mode of the page to determine if the text area should be displayed or not.

```
const  Myportal = (props) => {   
  const [ content, setContent ] = React.useState(props._content);
//abbreviated
  return (  
    <div className="App">
     { props._mode == 2 && <div>
       <textarea name="conent" id="conent" cols={30} rows={10} value={ props._content } onChange={ (evt) => { setContent(evt.target.value); } } 
 </textarea> <br />
  <button className="btn" onClick={ () => { props._updateWebPartContent(content) } } type="button" >Save Content</button> 
</div> }


<div className="modal-body">
  { props._content }
</div>
```